# How can I save the text value of the checkbox on Firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this error that says everytime I'll submit it:

> TypeError: s.indexOf is not a function

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const checkboxes = [
  { id: 1, text: "Checkbox 1" },
  { id: 2, text: "Checkbox 2" },
  { id: 3, text: "Checkbox 3" }
];

const SearchResults = () => {
  const [selectedCheckbox, setSelectedCheckbox] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (id) => {
    const findIdx = selectedCheckbox.indexOf(id);

    if (findIdx > -1) {
      selectedCheckbox.splice(findIdx, 1);
    } else {
      selectedCheckbox.push(id);
    }
    setSelectedCheckbox(selectedCheckbox);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedCheckbox));
try {
      const userRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
      const ref = userRef.set({
        selectedCheckbox
      });
     console.log("done")
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {checkboxes.map((checkbox) => (
            <label key={checkbox.id}>
              {checkbox.text}
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                onChange={() => handleChange(checkbox.text)}
                selected={selectedCheckbox.includes(checkbox.id)}
              />
            </label>
          ))}
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <p>Selected checkboxes: {JSON.stringify(selectedCheckbox)}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the codesandbox, though there's not Firestore data here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/handle-multiple-checkboxes-in-react-forked-xehxf?file=/src/App.js:0-2520

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the error rises when your tracking array of `selectedCheckbox`es goes `undefined` even though this is not quite the case in the linked code sandbox.

In *React* as a general rule, you should never mutate the state **even using React hooks** which is you case in the `handleChange` method.

You should update you event handler method as follows (always making a copy of the state array to construct a the new one):

```js
const handleChange = (id) => {
    const findIdx = selectedCheckbox.indexOf(id);

    let selected;
    if (findIdx > -1) {
      selected = selectedCheckbox.filter((checkboxId) => checkboxId !== id);
    } else {
      selected = [...selectedCheckbox, id];
    }
    setSelectedCheckbox(selected);
};
```

You click event handler takes the checkbox `id` as an argument and you should update you click handler accordingly:

```
<label key={checkbox.id}>
    {checkbox.text}
    <input
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={() => handleChange(checkbox.id)}
        selected={selectedCheckbox.includes(checkbox.id)}
     />
</label>
```